# Insert data to a stored procedure sqlalchemy + MSSQL server in python

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I am building some RestAPI's using python FastAPI and getting some data from MSSQL server using SQLAlchemy.

I am trying to insert data into existing stored procedure in MSSQL server.

The stored procedure `AcctsCostCentersAddV001` will take  `ArDescription, EngDescription, ErrMsg` as parameters and return `Output` as an output.

MSSQL Server Code:

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[AcctsCostCentersAddV001] @ArDescription nvarchar(100), @EngDescription varchar(100), @ErrMsg nvarchar(100) Output
As
Insert Into AcctsCostCenters (ArDescription, EngDescription) Values(@ArDescription, @EngDescription)
Set @ErrMsg = 'Test'
GO
```

My Python code:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

# # # # # # # # # #   SQL   # # # # # # # # # #
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError

# # # # # # # # # #  Files  # # # # # # # # # #
from dependencies import get_db
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from internal.config import username, password, SQL_SERVER, database_name



@router.get("/create/CostCenter/")
async def forms(request: Request, db=Depends(get_db)):
    try:


        connection_string = f'mssql://{username}:{password}@{SQL_SERVER}/{database_name}? 
        driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

        engine = create_engine(connection_string, pool_pre_ping=True)

        connection = engine.raw_connection()
        try:
            cursor_obj = connection.cursor()
            query = "Declare @ErrMsg  nvarchar(100) Exec AcctsCostCentersAddV001 'Test', 'Test', @ErrMsg Output Print @ErrMsg"
            cursor_obj.execute(text(query))
            results = list(cursor_obj.fetchall())
            cursor_obj.close()
            connection.commit()
            print(results)

        finally:
            connection.close()

    except IndexError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Not found")

    except ProgrammingError as e:
        print(e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid Entry")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return UnknownError(
            "unknown error caused by CostCenter API request handler", error=e)

    return JSONResponse(results)
```

For some reason, this code doesn't raise any exceptions but yet i keep getting

```
('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 3 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

I have even tried this

```
cursor_obj.execute("Declare @ErrMsg  nvarchar(100) Exec AcctsCostCentersAddV001 'Test', 'Test', @ErrMsg")
```

but i get back

```
No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

i tried wrapping the query in `text()` but i got `The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.`

but when i go into MSSQL Server and run

```
Declare @ErrMsg  nvarchar(100)
Exec AcctsCostCentersAddV001 'Test', 'Test', @ErrMsg Output
Print @ErrMsg
```

It runs without any problem.

My Env:

```
Ubuntu 21.04 VPS by OVH
```

I hope i am providing everything you guys need and let me know if missed anything, Thanks!

btw I know i am connecting to the db twice :3

(Edited):
I am actually connecting to the DB from a `datapase.py` file, and i am connecting again in the function just for testing.

My `database.py`:

```
import time
from colorama import Fore
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from internal.config import username, password, SQL_SERVER, database_name

try:

    connection_string = f'mssql://{username}:{password}@{SQL_SERVER}/{database_name}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

    engine = create_engine(connection_string, pool_pre_ping=True)

    connection = engine.raw_connection()

    print(f"{Fore.CYAN}DB{Fore.RESET}:       Database Connected.                                            ")

    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=True, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

    Base = declarative_base()


except Exception as e:
    print(f"{Fore.RED}DB{Fore.RESET}:        Couldn't connect to Database.", e)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mssql driver, but does it have a [callproc  method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-functions) that you should be using?

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures

Comment: Unfortunately for some reason pyodbc doesn't use ```.callpro()``` method

Comment: The github link didn't work for me too, i am starting to thing the problem is with SQL.